# Mongoose: Trying to filter users based on two fields using $and filters them as if I am using $or

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I have this function that should return **Active users in a given month who did not register in that month**. I.e: **Retained users**

```
const getActiveUsersInAMonthWereNotRegisteredInThatMonth = async (
  month,
  year
) => {
  let response = {
    active_users_who_were_not_registered_that_month: null,
  };

  // Group login event in a month by user id
  const login_project_stage = {
    $project: {
      year: { $year: "$date" },
      month: { $month: "$date" },
      user: "$user",
      category: "$category",
    },
  };
  const login_filter_stage = {
    $match: {
      year: parseInt(year),
      month: parseInt(month),
      category: "LOGIN",
    },
  };
  const active_users_group_stage = {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      number_of_logins: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  };

  const look_up_user_stage = {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user",
    },
  };

  const project_user_stage = {
    $project: {
      user_id: { $arrayElemAt: ["$user._id", 0] },
      registration_month: { $month: { $arrayElemAt: ["$user.date", 0] } },
      registration_year: { $year: { $arrayElemAt: ["$user.date", 0] } },
    },
  };

  const user_filter_stage = {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          registration_year: {
            $ne: parseInt(year),
          },
          registration_month: {
            $ne: parseInt(month),
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  const user_sum_stage = {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total_number_of_active_users_who_did_not_register_this_month: { $sum: 1 },
      users: {
        $push: "$$ROOT",
      },
    },
  };
  const login_pipeline = [
    login_project_stage,
    login_filter_stage,
    active_users_group_stage,
    look_up_user_stage,
    project_user_stage,
    user_filter_stage,
    user_sum_stage,
  ];
  const active_users_who_were_not_registered_that_month =
    await History.aggregate(login_pipeline);
  response.active_users_who_were_not_registered_that_month =
    active_users_who_were_not_registered_that_month;
  return response;
};
```

The problem is that this stage:

```
 const user_filter_stage = {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          registration_year: {
            $ne: parseInt(year),
          },
          registration_month: {
            $ne: parseInt(month),
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

Instead of filtering out **users who were registered in that month AND year**, it will filter out **users who were registered in that month OR year**.

So for example, if `month=7` and `year=2022`, any user who is registered in 2022 **OR** in July (7th month), will not be returned.

But, I only want it to filter users who were registed in 2022 **AND** in July (7th month).

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can try using the `$nor` query operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
  $nor: [
        {
          registration_year: parseInt(year),
          registration_month: parseInt(month),
        },
      ]
```